# Templating a table with ember.js not working with JSON call

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I've got an index page that lists taxes in a table. I'm trying to 
implement this with `ember.js` following some of the code in the 
contacts example app.

Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/1494281

When I don't load the content from JSON, by commenting out line 19 of 
`taxes.js`, the table renders correctly. However if I use the content 
that I pulled from `taxes.json` then the table renders without `tr` and 
`td` elements.

Script:

```
App.Tax = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.taxesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
   content: [
   {name:"tax1",rate:"10",number_id:"TaxIDNum"},
   {name:"tax2",rate:"9",number_id:null}
   ],
   newTax: function() {
   this.pushObject(App.Tax.create({}));
   },
   loadTaxes: function() {
   console.log('loadTaxes');
   var self = this;
   $.getJSON('/taxes.json', function(json) {
         console.log('got response', taxes);
         var taxes = json.map(function(item) {
                      return self.createTaxFromJSON(item);
                      });
         self.set('content', taxes);
         });
   },
   createTaxFromJSON: function(json) {
   console.log("createTaxFromJSON", json.tax);
   return App.Tax.create(json.tax);
   }
});

App.taxesController.loadTaxes();

App.selectedTaxController = Ember.Object.create({
    content: null
});

App.TaxListView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ['isSelected'],
    click: function() {
        var content = this.get('content');
        console.log('click', content);
        App.selectedTaxController.set('content', content);
    },
    isSelected: function() {
        var selectedItem = App.selectedTaxController.get('content');
        var content = this.get('content');
        if (content == selectedItem) {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }.property('App.selectedTaxController.content')
});

App.TaxView = Ember.View.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.selectedContactController.content'
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <table>
      {{#each App.taxesController.content}}
        {{#view App.TaxListView contentBinding="this" tagName="tr"}}
          {{#with content}}
          <td>{{name}}</td>
          <td>{{rate}}</td>
          <td>{{number_id}}</td>
          <td>
        <a href="#" class="nice tiny radius blue button">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="nice tiny radius red button">Delete</a>
          </td>
      {{/with}}
    {{/view}}
      {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

JSON:

```
[{"tax":{"account_id":1,"created_at":"2011-12-16T22:45:43Z","id":1,"name":"CA Sales Tax","number_id":"","rate":10.0,"updated_at":"2011-12-16T22:45:43Z"}},{"tax":{"account_id":1,"created_at":"2011-12-17T01:03:01Z","id":2,"name":"Second Tax","number_id":"EIN29387","rate":0.3,"updated_at":"2011-12-17T01:03:01Z"}}]
```

Comment: Are you on 0.9.2? I think there was a bug in 0.9.1 that messed up table rendering.

Comment: This seems to have worked in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the resulting HTML, you'll notice that ember added  tags inside your table. these are the markers for bindings to work

according to the HTML specification, inside a  tag there MUST only be , , ,  tags, everything else is undefined behaviour

to make it work, you'll have to remove the {{#view}} and it should at least render something useful.

Comment: This doesn't explain why fixture data was rendering correctly. Upgrading to 0.9.2 seems to have fixed this issue.